# In the blackbody radiation, would the energy distribution with wavelength take the same curve as the intensity distribution?

Tags: thermal-radiation, frequency, wavelength

Would the energy distribution take the same curve as the intensity distribution? In other words, can I derive the energy distribution by multiplying the Planck's radiation law by the surface area of a blackbody and the time duration ∆t?